# how to fetch data from url in mainactivity in android

Tags: java, android

the code i am using is working very fine for me but the problem is i am not able to fetch that data in main activity

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

            // get the array of users
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

            // loop through all users
            for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String firstname = c.getString("firstname");
                String lastname = c.getString("lastname");
                String username = c.getString("username");

                // show the values in our logcat
                Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname 
                        + ", lastname: " + lastname
                        + ", username: " + username);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
}
```

this is the code new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute(); to make this thing work

but i need to run

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // we will using AsyncTask during parsing 
    new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
}`
```

I want to get the data like firstname , lastname , username as variable in main activity .

Is it possible ??

this is my other class IncomingCall.java when i want to get the variables

```
           public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String username;




  public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    Toast.makeText(context, " Calling "+username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

    try {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                 TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                 || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                         TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            notifyuser=true;

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

        //Toast.makeText(context, "Error detected 1 "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }
  }


  public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>      {

    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl =     "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

            // get the array of users
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

            // loop through all users
           // for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                firstname = c.getString("firstname");
                lastname = c.getString("lastname");
                username = c.getString("username");

                // show the values in our logcat
                Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname 
                        + ", lastname: " + lastname
                        + ", username: " + username);

           // }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Here you use your variables
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {


         Log.e("TAG1", "firstname: " + firstname 
                 + ", lastname: " + lastname
                 + ", username: " + username);


    }
}
```

this is my code

Comment: i want just like this [link](http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/12/android-json-parsing-from-url)

Here you can see 
           wid.setText(json.getString("id"));
            name.setText(json.getString("name"));
            url.setText(json.getString("url"));

this variable i am getting in mainactivity

Comment: Is the AsyncTaskParseJson class a nested class of your Main Activity? If that's the case, use the class variables of Main Activity to store your strings.

Comment: no its on different java file named "jsonParser.java" , its this java file Json object is returning 

same as this one [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html)

but i want to to execute method in activity , i want to get variables of json in MainActivity

Comment: So is it inside another activity? Or is just a stand-alone class? In that case, what's the reason to extend the AsyncTask?

Comment: because if i don't use AsyncTask then i will get eror "android.os.networkonmainthreadexception"

Comment: when i use this 

     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}

its solved my problem but i want to use AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in your Main Activity class, and then use class variables to store what you want, e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String[] firstname;
    private String[] lastname;
    private String[] username;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();

    }

    public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

        // set your json string url here
        String yourJsonStringUrl =     "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php";

        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            try {

                // instantiate our json parser
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

                // get json string from url
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

                // get the array of users
                dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");


                firstname = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];
                lastname = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];
                username = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];

                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    firstname[i] = c.getString("firstname");
                    lastname[i] = c.getString("lastname");
                    username[i] = c.getString("username");

                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname 
                            + ", lastname: " + lastname
                            + ", username: " + username);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Here you use your variables
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
    }
}
```

Something like this (it's without error checking, give it a try)

EDIT: be sure to have declared the internet permission in the android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: yes permission is allowed

but variable retuning me "null" value

not works

Comment: @RajdeepKumar
Edited the code, added a runOnUiThread() where you should use your variables.

P.s. how do you test the variable values?

Comment: new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
      
      Log.e("execute","execute "+username+firstname+lastname);

using this i am check values

Comment: @RajdeepKumar Yes it does. I tried myself and it works, the values are stored in the variables and you can use them freely in runOnUiThread(), I have made one last edit in order to get all the data and store them in an array and not only the last one. I don't know what, but you're doing something wrong if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: this is the error i am geting "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson"

my class name is IncomingCall.java

Comment: Copy that code and put a System.out(firstname[0]) in the runOnUiThread(), and see in the logcat that the variable is printed.

Comment: yes it works for MainActivity but not works for my other class "IncomingCall.java" which extends BroadcastReceiver

 
this is the error i am geting "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson" my class name is IncomingCall.java

Comment: You did not mention another class in your question, that's why I was confused. Anyway, I don't know nothing about tour application's flow, you may pass the data via Intent, or some other ways. It depends.

Answer (score 1):

The method onPostExecute runs on the main thread, You need to use the data once the doInBackground finishes and control return to the main thread.

Better you use these data in the method

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
   // use the firstname , lastname or username after this method call.
   }
```

Comment: can you explain it please

is it like this


        protected void onPostExecute(String c) {
         firstname = c.getString("firstname");
            lastname = c.getString("lastname");
            username = c.getString("username");
         
        }

??

Comment: could you please explain me how would be pass the value in onPostExecute since i don't have any String returning value

Comment: i did this

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
         
         
          Log.e("TAG1", "firstname: " + firstname 
                     + ", lastname: " + lastname
                     + ", username: " + username);
        }

and found that variable showing correct value but how to pass this value in MainActivity ??